# Backbone model.get('key') undefined after .fetch() call, even inside success callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm new to Backbone.js, and just finished running through a basic tutorial to create a "user list" system (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZSjvWtUxYk) where all the templates, scripts, etc are created inline. I got everything working pretty easily, so I decided to try and modularize things since I know that's the best practice. I'm following this guide to the AMD methodology (https://cdnjs.com/libraries/backbone.js/tutorials/organizing-backbone-using-modules) and have everything working properly except for one thing - when editing a user, the "current" data isn't being loaded into the form. All of the issues I've found on SO and other places so far have been solved by putting the template generating code inside the success: callback of the .fetch() call, but I'm already doing that.

Here's the code:

(I'm leaving out the main.js and app.js that handle the require.js configuration, router init, etc. They seem to be working just fine.)

```
// Filename: router.js
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'views/userList',
  'views/editUser'
], function($, _, Backbone, UserListView, EditUserView){
  var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      '': 'home',
      'new': 'editUser',
      'edit/:id': 'editUser'
    }
  });

  var initialize = function(){
    var app_router = new AppRouter;

    app_router.on('route:home', function(){
      var userListView = new UserListView();

      userListView.render();
    });

    app_router.on('route:editUser', function(id) {
      var editUserView = new EditUserView();

      editUserView.render({ id: id });
    });

    Backbone.history.start();
  };

  return {
    initialize: initialize
  };
});
```

views/editUser.js

```
// Filename: views/editUser
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/user',
  'text!/templates/editUser.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, UserModel, rawEditUserTemplate) {
  var userListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // Element to use for this view
    el: $('.page'),

    // Function to call when this view is rendered
    render: function(options) {
      var that = this;

      // If there is an ID, we are editing
      if ( options.id ) {
        // Create the user, passing the ID
        that.editUser = new UserModel({ id: options.id });

        // Fetch the user data
        that.editUser.fetch({
          // When the fetch is returned
          success: function(userData) {
            // Generate the template and pass the data in
            var editUserTemplate = _.template( rawEditUserTemplate );
            that.$el.html(editUserTemplate({ user: userData }));
          }
        })
      }
      else { // We are creating a new user
        // Generate the template with an empty user
        var editUserTemplate = _.template( rawEditUserTemplate );
        this.$el.html(editUserTemplate({ user: null }));
      }
    },
    events: {
      'submit .edit-user-form': 'saveUser',
      'click .delete': 'deleteUser'
    },
    saveUser: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      // Get the details
      var userDetails = $(e.currentTarget).serializeObject();

      // Create a user model
      var user = new UserModel();

      // Save the user details
      user.save(userDetails, {
        success: function(user) {
          Backbone.history.navigate('', { trigger: true });
        }
      });
    },
    deleteUser: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      // Destroy the user we are editing
      this.editUser.destroy({
        // When the destroy is finished
        success: function() {
          // Back to home
          Backbone.history.navigate('', { trigger: true });
        }
      });
    }
  });

  // Our module now returns our view
  return userListView;
});
```

templates/editUser.html

```
<form class="edit-user-form">
  <legend><%= user ? 'Update' : 'Create' %> User</legend>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="<%= user ? user.get('firstname') : '' %>" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="<%= user ? user.get('lastname') : '' %>" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="age">Age</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="age" id="age" value="<%= user ? user.get('age') : '' %>" />
  </div>

  <hr />

  <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"><%= user ? 'Update' : 'Create' %></button>

  <% if ( user ) { %>
  <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<%= user.id %>" />
  <button class="btn btn-danger delete">Delete</button>
  <% }; %>
</form>
```

Using this code, I get a blank edit form regardless of whether or not I'm editing or creating, HOWEVER the "Create" vs "Update" text switch in the template is working properly. This means that a user object is in fact being passed, and when I add a console.log(user) into the template file, it is in fact showing me user data. When I log user.get('firstname') or any other attribute, however, it logs "undefined".

Comment: at the first glance it looks good for me. Are you sure the returned JSON response contains the properties? What can you see if you console.log(userData.attributes) in the success callback?

Comment: This is what it logs: http://i.imgur.com/wye24pA.png that's the correct data

Comment: no thats not correct data. That is an object with 2 keys: "0" and "id" and all the properties are placed into the object with the "0" key. Your response JSON is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the actual User information was correct. So you're saying that the API is giving me the data in an incorrect format?

Comment: yes. Your actual response is an object with 2 keys ("0" and "id") but you need a response with "id", "age", "firstname", "lastname" keys.

Comment: Thank you, this led me to figuring out the answer. Posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in my User model, which I didn't include above because I didn't understand at the time why it could be relevant.

I was defining it as:

```
var userModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: '/users'
});
```

When it should have been:

```
var userModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: '/users'
});
```

The wrong option was causing the API to return a collection rather than a model, so the .get() wasn't able to work properly.